# How does the London force work at absolute zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase

Consider a molecule such as pentane which is mostly attracted to other molecules by dispersion forces. If there is no heat and no fluctuations in electron positions how would a liquid or solid hold together?

I am not sure that zero point energy would work to keep this together.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me

Comment: "no fluctuations in electron positions" - that's not true. Cooling doesn't change anything in this matter.

Comment: As this is 'on hold' i can only comment. The dispersion energy is proportional to the square of the polarisability and to the ionisation energy and to inverse distance to  6th power. The polarisability is a measure of how easily a nearly (transient) dipole can distort the electrons in an atom or molecule. Iodine large effect, pentane small one. Thus the interaction energy has nothing to do with temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, kinetic energy of electrons is greatest in the ground state of an atom or molecule.

But regarding your actual question, according to quantum electrodynamics, the vacuum consists of fluctuating electric fields.  The electric field polarizes the atom or molecule, even in the ground state, and there is attraction between the polarized atoms or molecules.http://george.ph.utexas.edu/~dsteck/reading/casimir/milonni94.pdf

Answer (score 3):

- You assume that absolute zero can be reached - but it is not
  possible.
- You assume that at absolute zero the molecules would have
  any kinetic energy to  drift apart - but they would not have.
- You  assume that absolute zero temperature means no fluctuation -  I am
  not sure about that either.

In summary, you picked a non-physical state and you are trying to apply your physical intuition on it.